# .net console app stop responding when printing out lots of chars in a row

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am trying to figure out why a program I am working on goes in to "not responding" mode when I ask it to output a large amount of characters to the console it is running in.

I tried creating a small example that just prints out characters, and this will indeed also go "not responding" on me after some 10-20 seconds:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i = (i+1) % 255)
    {
        Console.Write(((char)i));

    }
}
```

The program is still running though, even though the console window is "not responding", I can still pause the debugger and continue it, but the console window is broken.

The thing is, the console do not mind spitting out an endless amount of integers:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i = (i+1) % 255)
    {
        Console.Write(i);            
    }
}
```

Any ideas is much appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it will spew out a lot of nonsense (and beep a lot, unless you mask out character 7, which is a bell) but it never becomes unresponsive for me.

It will depend on how your console handles control characters though - which console are you using, on which operating system and with which language?

Moreover, why do you *want* to send unprintable characters to the console? If you keep your loop to ASCII (32-126) what happens? For example:

```
using System;

class Test
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i=32;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write((char)i);
            i++;
            if (i == 127)
            {
                i = 32;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does that still exhibit the same behaviour?

You mention the debugger - do you get the same behaviour if you run outside the debugger? (I've only tested from the command line so far.)

Comment: Tried it both in and out of visual studio, running Windows 7 (us, with Danish as regional), from the regular cmd.exe console. Your example works fine though, and after modifying to include 0-255 but excluding 7, my console continues to print characters without a problem. So I guess it is the beep that kills it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5):

When you cast it to a character, you're also sending control characters to the console for some lower values of `i`.  I'd guess is has something to do with outputting some of those control characters repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an aside, you can omit `i<255` and simply write:
`for (int i = 0; ;i = (i+1) % 255 )`

or to go with Jon's answer you can simplify that like this

```
using System;

class Test
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for(var i=0;;i=(i+1) % 126)
        {
            Console.Write((char)(i+32));
        }
    }
}
```