# How do I make a console application appear "Not Responding"?

Tags: c#, console-application

For testing, what is the easiest way to make a program appear *"Not Responding"*? Interrupt Windows messages or put it in an infinite loop?

I have tried a simple loop like

```
while(true)
```

But that does not work.
The test application is a C# console app. Does the fact that it's running in a console make it "more responsive"? Perhaps there are some parts of the added console handling that make it respond all the time?

**Update:**

Changed it to a simple Winform Application put that into an infinite loop. Worked lika a charm. Thanks to Servy.

Comment: I have another app that it meant to "catch" applications "Not Responding". And thus I need to make a small app that I can force into becoming unresponsive for test purposes.

Comment: @Servy: Ok, so change it to a simple UI app and put it spiraling down an infinite loop and it should do it for me?

Comment: @inquam If you want to mimic a program "not responding" from the point of view of task manager you should make a simple winforms application and put that in an infinite loop, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A console application will never be "Not Responding" from the point of view of Windows Task Manager. In reality task manager isn't running your program, it's running a shell (cmd.exe) that is running your program, and that shell is written such that it will always be responding even if your program isn't. If you aren't running your program through a shell but are starting it directly, then there won't be any UI for the program and it won't be an "Application" in task manager (meaning it won't show up in the "Application" tab), it will just be a process.

If you just need to mimic any program "Not Responding" from the point of view of task manager you should make a simple winforms application and put that in an infinite loop.  If there is some obscure way of making a program appear "Not Responding" from a console app, at the very least it will be much harder than from any of the standard desktop GUI types.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `Thread.Sleep(X)`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make a program 'not responding' indefinitely is to use an infinite loop:

```
while(true);
```

Comment: I didn't see the word "indefinitely" in the OP; he may want some way of making it respond again without killing the program.

Answer (score 1):

Do any work on the UI thead (for a UI application)

```
Thread.Sleep  



  While (true)
```

this might give some insight into more of what your trying to accomplish ([.net console app stop responding when printing out lots of chars in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912373/net-console-app-stop-responding-when-printing-out-lots-of-chars-in-a-row))